# Programação Orientada a Objeto

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, delphi

Eu venho desenvolvendo projetos em delphi desde a época do pascal, mas meu grande problema eh que eu nunca me mantive muito atualizado as mudanças e sempre usei uma linguagem processual e agora eu preciso aprender a programar com objetos porque na firma que estou trabalhando todos os códigos usam essa filosofia.

Eu estou tentando aprender mas tem sido difícil encontrar bom material que explique a programação orientada objeto voltada a Delphi e também algo que não comece explicando variáveis, laços e condições porque não exite motivos para isso.

Alguém aqui sabe alguma boa indicação de livro, tutorial ou pagina para me indicar?

Comment: Nossa plataforma não é boa para lidar com lista de itens. A pergunta está muito aberta. Quase qualquer coisa postada aqui poderia ser um resposta. Nós precisamos ter respostas que possam ser escolhidas como certa. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/507/perguntas-verdadeiras-tem-respostas

Comment: Desculpa nao tinha lido essa parte ainda, pode deixar nao vai acontecer novamento, Grato pelo esclarecimento.

Comment: Legal que você quer aprender algo novo. É um pouco difícil de achar material online pra Delphi, mesmo. Mas como qualquer estilo de programação, o melhor jeito de aprender é tentando (de preferência num ambiente controlado, não no código do sistema que vc está trabalhando, hehe). Você faz algumas besteiras no começo, mas depois a coisa engrena -- portanto, não desanime. Orientação a objetos é um conceito independente de linguagem, então você poderia aproveitar o ensejo para aprender também uma linguagem nova: sugiro Python ou Ruby. =)

Comment: Seguem links para [tutorial de Python](http://turing.com.br/pydoc/2.7/tutorial/index.html) ou [tutorial de Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/pt/documentation/quickstart/) em português. Boa sorte nos estudos.

Comment: Não tem problema. Todos nós demoramos para entender esse negócio tão diferente e tão interessante. O preço que temos que pagar para manter ao lato nível da troca de conhecimento é não aceitar qualquer coisa que não seja estritamente **perguntas** e **respostas**.

Comment: Material sobre Object Pascal (outro nome para o Delphi) em português: [link](http://pt.scribd.com/doc/29203105/Programacao-Orientada-a-Objetos-Com-Object-Pascal). É isso que você queria? Achei googlando por pascal orientado a objetos.

Answer (score 3):

Vou deixar o link de um vídeo que recomendo bastante.
Ele tem C# no título, mas não entra em detalhes da linguagem, ele apenas explica como funciona a POO que vale para todas as linguagens que usam esse conceito.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-nrQR7Pgak